# C++ CreateThread() strange error

Tags: c++, windows, createthread

I try to use CreateThread() function in my application, but I get strange error, exactly:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'DWORD (__ attribute__((__ stdcall__)) *)() {aka long unsigned int (__ attribute__((__ stdcall__)) *)()}' to 'LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE {aka long unsigned int (__ attribute__((__ stdcall__)) *)(void*)}' [-fpermissive]
```

and

```
In file included from c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/windows.h:50:0,

             from c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/winsock2.h:22,
             from c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/ws2tcpip.h:19,
             from include/WinSockClass.hpp:3,
             from C:\Users\Jakub\Desktop\offline\Server\main.cpp:15:
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../include/winbase.h:1423:26: error:   initializing argument 3 of 'void* CreateThread(LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, DWORD, LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE, PVOID, DWORD, PDWORD)' [-fpermissive]
```

second indicates line

```
WINBASEAPI HANDLE WINAPI CreateThread(LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,DWORD,LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE,PVOID,DWORD,PDWORD);
```

in winbase.h, I don't understand what going on, in examples is same thing, but without error. What I do wrong ?

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int a()
{
   cout << "work";
   return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    CreateThread(NULL,0,a,NULL,0,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, how are you calling `CreateThread()` actually?

Comment: The error message says exactly what is wrong. You passed the wrong type of function pointer. The error message says both what you passed and what you were supposed to pass.

Comment: The thread function *must* be defined correctly.  See [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686736(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

OK, is my fault, that works

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

DWORD WINAPI a(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
   cout << "work";
   return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    CreateThread(NULL,0,a,NULL,0,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```